# How to input and store long ints from a file to process it in a c++

Tags: c++, file, io, long-integer

So i have a long int dataset with about 3-4 million numbers in a .txt file which is one number per line
and i want to take the numbers as an input for my program, i am not sure how to get it right, for my current code i am getting a segmentation fault

```
long long int *buff;
buff = (long long int*) malloc(100000000 * sizeof(long long int));
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("out6.txt","r");
while(fscanf(fp,"%lli",buff));
for(int i=0;i!=EOF,i++){
filter(to_string(buff[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
free(buff)
```

and my function is pretty simple so, if there is a way i can use to avoid storing the numbers, it would be great

```
int filter(string num){
   for(int i=0;i<num.size();i++){
       if(num[i]=='0'||num[i]=='8'){
           return 0;
       }
       if((num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='8') || (num[i]=='2' && num[i+1]=='9') || (num[i]=='6' && num[i+1]=='3') || (num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='2') || (num[i]=='2' && num[i+1]=='1') || (num[i]=='6' && num[i+1]=='1') || (num[i]=='6' && num[i+1]=='1')
        || (num[i]=='9' && num[i+1]=='2') || (num[i]=='3' && num[i+1]=='6') || (num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='1') 
        || (num[i]=='8' && num[i+1]=='1') || (num[i]=='4' && num[i+1]=='5') || (num[i]=='5' && num[i+1]=='4') || (num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='3') || (num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='4') || (num[i]=='4' && num[i+1]=='8') || (num[i]=='8' && num[i+1]=='4') 
        || (num[i]=='7' && num[i+1]=='9')|| (num[i]=='9' && num[i+1]=='7') || (num[i]=='6' && num[i+1]=='6') || (num[i]=='2' && num[i+1]=='4') || (num[i]=='4' && num[i+1]=='2') || (num[i]=='2' && num[i+1]=='7') || (num[i]=='7' && num[i+1]=='2') || (num[i]=='4' && num[i+1]=='7') || (num[i]=='7' && num[i+1]=='4') || (num[i]=='7' && num[i+1]=='1') || (num[i]=='1' && num[i+1]=='7')){
           return 0;
           
           //cout<<"There exists a BAD combination of "<<num[i]<<" and "<<num[i+1]<<endl;
       }
   }
   cout<<num<<endl;
}
```

EDIT #1
so i have added the filter function, i have added a for loop to filter each number,
i know the for loop is wrong, need a way to iterate through the numbers and also if there was a way to use filter on one number at a time without storing that would be great too. changed %li to %lli. using strings to input is also acceptable

Comment: You should read those numbers as strings.

Comment: There is no need to store the number, just read and filter one at a time

Comment: `while(fscanf(fp,"%li",&buff));` is very wrong. (1) `buff` is already a pointer, so no need for the `&`. (2) You're reading each line/number into the *same* address - use `&buff[i]`, possibly, and increment `i` after each read.

Comment: I suggest using anything but `malloc`. Have you tried `std::vector<long long> buff;`?

Comment: `"%li"` is the fromat for `long int`. For `long long int` you need `"%lli"`

Comment: `num[i+1]` makes your program have undefined behavior. `i+1` will become `== num.size()` so you access `num` out of bounds

Comment: I think you want to read 1 line at a time into a std::string using std::getling() and process the string.

Comment: `int filter(string num){` probably should be `void filter(string num){` not sure why you return an `int` however not all code paths return a value making the code broken. Since the calling code does not use the return value the best solution is to remove it.

Comment: You might want to grab a beginners C++ book. This sort of error pretty much disappears when you stop writing C code. A `std::vector<long long int>` does the whole memory management for you.

Comment: just use some library [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/) for example

Comment: Addtionally, C++ code offers much simpler idioms for reading formatted input from a file, and it will avoid the simple typo in the shown code that resulted in this segmentation fault.

Comment: What is the largest number in the file?

Comment: There are bugs preventing this from working on a file with small numbers. You should step through it with a debugger.

Comment: the largest number in the range is 9999999999, and the length of the list doesnt exceed 15 million

Comment: @KarthikR Ok, great - but please don't put code from the answers you get into your question. That changes the question fundamentally. I rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your objective is but it looks like:

- You want to read `long long`s from a file.
- You want to filter some of them out.
- You'd like to apply the filter by looking at the numbers as strings.

Since C++20, we have [`std::ranges::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy) with projection:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fs("out6.txt");  // open the file

    std::vector<long long> result; // to store all the "ok" numbers

    // copy only those numbers from the file for which the filter returns `true`
    // using a projection to convert each number to a string before the filtering:

    std::ranges::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<long long>(fs), // read long long's from "fs"
        std::istream_iterator<long long>{},   // until it fails reading more
        std::back_inserter(result),           // where to store "ok" numbers
        [](const std::string& ll) noexcept {  // filter
            // your complicated filter logic
            // goes in here
            return true; // or false
        },
        [](long long ll) {                    // projection
            return std::to_string(ll);
        });

    // print the result
    for(long long v : result) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tc8Y8eehP)

In C++11 to C++17, you could use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (with "manual" projection):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fs("out6.txt");  // open the file

    std::vector<long long> result; // to store all the "ok" numbers

    // copy only those numbers from the file for which the filter returns `true`
    // using a projection to convert each number to a string before the filtering:

    std::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<long long>(fs), // read long long's from "fs"
        std::istream_iterator<long long>{},   // until it fails reading more
        std::back_inserter(result),           // where to store "ok" numbers
        [](long long in) noexcept {           // filter
            std::string ll = std::to_string(in); // the manual projection part
            // your complicated filter logic
            // goes in here
            return true; // or false
        });

    // print the result
    for(long long v : result) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gnad5fvna)

Comment: $ g++ -std=c++2a number.cpp
number.cpp: In function 'int main()':
number.cpp:141:10: error: 'std::ranges' has not been declared
  141 |     std::ranges::copy_if(
      |          ^~~~~~    (im getting this error, also please check the filter syntax in edit #2 as im not well versed with c++20)

Comment: @KarthikR Perhaps your compiler is a bit too old. `std::ranges::copy_if` should be in `<algorithm>` in C++20. I added a demo where you can see how it _should_ work. The actual filter looks complicated and I'm not even sure what the rules for the filter are. Perhaps I'd understand what it's supposed to be doing if if you wrote the filtering rules in the question.

Comment: @KarthikR I also added a version that should work if you have a compiler that doesn't support `std::ranges::copy_if`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Ted your solution helped me finally finish my program.it is finally working :)

Comment: @KarthikR Glad to hear it! You're welcome!